# Javascript Value Replace for Multiple Values

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I am trying to replace multiple values in a string with JS replace().  The values that I want to replace include line breaks, &, #, etc...  I know how to replace one value:

```
var string = document.getElementById('string').value.replace(\/n/g, '<br>');
```

However, what is the syntax to include other values.  For example, how can I make the below replace functions one function?

```
var string = document.getElementById('string').value.replace(\/n/g, '<br>')
var string = document.getElementById('string').value.replace('&', '%26');
```

Comment: You could create an object of strings and replacements: `{ '&': '%26, ' ': '%20', ... }` and then loop through to do the replacements, but I think @xdazz's answer is probably just as good or better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could chain it simply.

```
var string = document.getElementById('string').value.replace(/\n/g, '<br>').replace('&', '%26');
```

Comment: Thanks - At first I tried your solution, before posting to this forum, however the second replace was only working for the first occurrence of the value.  After your suggestion, I also included forward slashes to &, #, and other symbols, and that did the trick - Thank you