# Finding multiple characters and replacing with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following JQuery AJAX call that sends HTML form data to my server side script to deal with. However I currently find line breaks and convert them to `<br />` for display in another part of my application. I now need to make sure I am stripping out apostrophes however I am not confident on how to replace multiple characters in one go.

This is the JQuery I use currently before adding this into my AJAX.

```
description = $("#description").val().replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Value Replace for Multiple Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073372/javascript-value-replace-for-multiple-values)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't have to do it in one go in the sense of one call to `.replace()`, just chain multiple `.replace()` calls:

```
description = $("#description").val().replace(/\n/g, '<br />')
                                     .replace(/'/g, '');
```

(Or replace with `'&#39;'` or `'&apos;'` if that's what you need...)

Comment: This is spot on! I did no think it woul dbe that simple!

Comment: Also, can anyone tell me why my origional replace(), might cause it to replace "0" with ""...

Answer (score 2):

I agree with nnnnnn that you don't have to do it all in one go though you can use the or `|` regex operator and use a callback like below, see [mdn regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for more details

```
var foo = '"there are only 10 people in this world that understand binary, 
            \n those who can and those who can\'t"\n some joke';

foo = foo.replace(/\n|"/g, function(str) {
  if (str == '\n') {
    return '<br/>';
  } else {
    return '';
  }
});

document.write(foo);
```

here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/ihuvak/2/edit#javascript,html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use | (pipe) to include multiple characters to replace:

```
str = str.replace(/X|x/g, '');
```

(see my fiddle here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gerritb/HpBc2/2/))

Answer (score 1):

The `.serialize()` method uses `encodeURIComponent` to encode all of your fields in a form so you don't have to manually escape strings.

If it's not in a form just use:

```
description = encodeURIComponent($("#description").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This
Put your values in variables and replace.

```
 $(function () {
            var s = "str";
            var t = "nw str";
            alert(s.replace(s, t));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create function recursive

```
function replaceBr(){
  var val = $("#description").val();    
  while (val !=(val = val.replace(/\n/g, '<br />')));
  return val;
}
```

thx

Comment: The g flag in the regex means all the occurrences of the pattern will be replaced, you don't need to add a loop.